# Two PCAN Adapters to two USB Ports of same Laptop

Tags: python

I am struggling with a problem of reading through two PCAN adaptors for CAN messages. Both the PCAN adapters are connected to the USB Ports of the windows laptop.
One CAN adaptor is trying to read the CAN messages and other is reading the DID through UDS. When i run the code, both UDS and CAN code use the same USB port, making my application not work.CAN Library: https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/ UDS Library:  https://udsoncan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
import can
import time
import sys

bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype = 'pcan', channel ='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate = 500000)     # Windows

bus1= PcanBus(channel='PCAN_USBBUS2', bitrate=500000)  # udsoncan library



class changeState:    

    def Receive_Can_Message(self):

        message = bus.recv(1)
        print(message)

  class UDS:
  def ReadingUDSMessage()
 // Detail UDS message
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj= changeState()
     obj2.UDS()
    while True:      
        obj.Receive_Can_Message()
        obj2.ReadingUDSMessage()
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a second `Bus` object using `channel = 'PCAN_USBBUS2'`?

Comment: Yes i tried. But it didnot worked for me.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about the problem than "did not work".

Comment: It works. Thank you.

Comment: @ManuChaudhary  mind to answer your own question?

Comment: Hi jasonharper, i have edited the question. I am trying to read DID through UDS client through one PCAN adaptor connected to laptop at USB Port  and another PCAN adapter connected to Laptop through another USB Port. The problem is only that i am only able to Read the DID but no can message is read

Comment: Hi Paolo, the problem is still not solved. Please review the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you using two Peak CAN adaptors to an application related to python can library, you have use channel='PCAN_USBBUS1' for first and channel='PCAN_USBBUS2' for other. Also, take care to put the peak CAN adaptor to a laptop in correct sequence. The first connected USB to a laptop is considered channel='PCAN_USB1' and next one is considered 'PCAN_USB2'.